# 404 Error Hosting WCF Service via IIS 7.5 Shared Content

Tags: wcf, iis, http-status-code-404

We're attempting to host a WCF Service (.NET 3.5 SP1) using Shared Content on IIS 7.5. At the moment it's returning a 404 error. My assumption at this point is that WCF can not be hosted via a UNC path (See workaround[Hosting WCF service in IIS6 using UNC](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/132ac327-d595-499d-b3e8-b953499b7f0c)).

Steps I've taken:
 - Established a FullTrust to/with the UNC path.
 - The service works hosting it on a local disk.
 - A basic HTML page renders without issue from the UNC path.
 - A ASPX page renders without issue from the UNC path.
 - Explicitly set "Full Control" permissions to the user running the service.

The reason for using Shared Content in IIS 7.5 to host this WCF Service, and several other websites, in a web farm. Using Shared Content avoids the need for file replication between the nodes in the farm. (Note we are also using Shared Configuration to support this environment.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you used fiddler to inspect the traffic?
Or enabled [failed request tracing](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/266/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-7/) in IIS?

Comment: I just installed tracing now, however i'm not receiving any output to the folder. I restart the server, even though it didn't require it after installing tracing. It's interesting that I'm unable to select "WWW Server" in the filter though, only "ASP.NET".

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the root of the issue revolves around the identity of the application pool being set to "ApplicationPoolIdentity" (Application Pool/[App Pool]/Advanced Settings/Process Model/Identity). We were setting the proper user credentials at the website, but not here.

We now have the application pool running as the user and the website using pass-through authentication.